# Why is R reading only the first nine files

Tags: r, regex, readxl

I'm reading multiple .xls from a folder "test_dir" with this code

```
library(readxl)
files <- list.files(path = "./test_dir", pattern = "*.xls", full.names = T)
tbl <- sapply(files, read_excel, simplify=FALSE, skip=7) %>% 
bind_rows(.id = "id")
```

each time, only the first 9 dataset are read into r i.e Book1-Book9, do anyone know the reason why ?
see the structure of my folder in the image below [image: Folder Structure]
[Sample Data](https://www.dropbox.com/transfer/AAAAAKC7iqPtvk9P-7Ro2R2pc-3qSV3LzP1jCkC6aGEsWNWoudmKVIA)

Comment: Though I don't know if this is *the* problem, your regex is wrong. `pattern=` is a regular expression, but what you're providing is a file glob; see `glob2rx("*.xls")` to see what the (perfectly) equivalent regex would be for that. (You can also just use `pattern="\\.xls$"` which should be sufficient.)

Comment: What makes you believe that only files 1-9 have been read?

Comment: @r2evans if I understand regex *, it needs something before it so it should not work at all?

Comment: I don't know about *"not work at all"*, since I think the regex engine is optimizing the leading (and therefore no-op) `*` out of it. Two things: (1) I don't think the regex is your problem, but it is wrong. It might not be breaking now, but if you continue to think that it is using file globbing and you use something more complex, it will not find what you want it to. (2) Ultimately, since I don't know why you say that only files 1-9 have been read, I really don't know what's going on. If this question were a bit more reproducible (make 12 fake csv files?), I might be able to test it locally.

Comment: @r2evans, "What makes you believe that only files 1-9 have been read?" because i check the df created !

Comment: @r2evans, the suggested `pattern="\\.xls$"` only read in the first 9 workbooks. Please give it a try.

Comment: Hammao, have you tried opening each of the files individually? When I tried (though generally do not follow links), I can open a few but most return `# A tibble: 0 x 0`. When I try to view it in Excel, it warns me that the file is corrupt and data may have been lost. While Excel *does* show me non-empty data, apparently Excel can salvage more than `readxl` can salvage. Perhaps you can find versions of those files that are not corrupted?

Comment: So your question should instead be *"Why does <this> file not open with `readxl::read_excel`?"* This question has nothing to do with numerous files. If you try to `bind_rows` empty frames, it is going to do nothing, and do it *silently*, so you don't know that many (most?) of the files are empty. If you don't pipe it and instead store `tbl <- sapply(files, readxl::read_excel, skip=7)`, you can then try `sapply(tbl, NROW)` and see that the problematic files are all zeroes. Good luck.

Comment: @RonakShah... Same only the first 9 were read with your code. The behaviour is weird that's why i needed a second opinion

Comment: Ronak, if you use `lapply` like that, the `.id="id"` is useless since `lapply` is not preserving names. That's about the only advantage of `sapply(..., simplify=FALSE)` in times like these.

Comment: @r2evans, the files were generated from a software, so that warning always comes up... but i've opened all the files before and they all have contents. My surprise is why reading the files stops at Book9

Comment: I'll be clear: I can open 1, 9, and 10, nothing else. In fact, the first few times I could open 1 and 9, not 10, so ... it appears to be a bug with `readxl::read_excel`. In fact, I just tried again and loaded 1, 2, 9, and 10. So it is almost definitely a bug. I suggest you [create a bug report](https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/new), as the non-deterministic behavior is annoying.

Comment: My last comment: given the stochastic nature I'm seeing on my console, it might be possible to write a function that repeatedly attempts to load a file and stops when it loads or after `n` tries. In fact, you may want to do that until somebody submits a PR to `readxl`, it is accepted, and then a version updated to CRAN ... which might take a while.

Comment: I agree with r2evans, but I don't see any stochastic nature. There is something weird going on though, either with the readxl package or with those Excel files themselves. If you open them one by one (using Excel), and then just quit (without saving), they can then be imported into R.

Comment: Edward, the only reason I'm thinking stochastic is because I verified one more could be read while I was typing those comments above. I can't reproduce it, and I just `replicate(1000, ...)`'ed it to verify. Hammao, if those files are being produced programmatically, do you have the ability to change how they are being created? It's broken somehow, and there are several ways that would be more reliable than corrupted `.xls` files.

Comment: @r2evans, i will try saving them as .txt files for now pending when someone comments on the bug report. many thanks

Comment: @Hammao. You opened Books 1 and 9, didn't you? But not the others. After unzipping those files, I can only import Books 1 and 9. r2evans. Unzip the files again (delete the ones you have) and try to import. Do you get Book1 and 9 only? Now open another Book in Excel and then close the file (without saving). Try again. That other book can now be imported.

Comment: Good point, Edward!, that could explain what I thought was random. Interesting that Excel is updating the file despite me never saying "Save". (I say "Interesting", but I'm really thinking "Truly Annoying".)

Comment: Excel does some "interesting" silent saving even when you quit without saving. I say "interesting", but I'm really thinking "Evil"). Data that 'look' like dates are a prime example. BTW, has anyone tried another package to import the files? xlsxl or XLConnect?

Comment: @Edward, I didn't open any of the files... infact, that is why the weird behavior is surprising... r2evans, had suggested that i open and save the files but i'm yet to do that. Why the first 9 !

Comment: @Hammao. It's not the first 9 files. It's only file 1 and 9. Try to read in files 2-8 using read_excel, one by one, manually. `read_excel("Book2.xls")`. It won't give an error, but you'll see an empty tibble. Do for all files 1-9. Do this before you open and close them. If you didn't open those two files (Book1 and Book9), then someone else must have, or they weren't generated by the same software that generated the other files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a lot of comments here. I'll try to synthesize them into one clear answer. The original poster (OP) is trying into read multiple Excel workbooks into R using the `read_excel` function from the excellent R package called **readxl**. OP says only the first 9 workbooks could be imported. After providing the files via DropBox, r2evans could only import workbooks 1, 9 and 10 while I could only import workbooks 1 and 9. On further interrogation, OP said that the files were "generated from a software".

I am quite certain that therein lies the problem. The Excel files were generated by software, presumably not by Excel. The OP didn't say what software generated the files. The fact that they said "software", and not Excel, would imply that Excel did not create the files.

I also believe that workbooks 1 and 9 were opened by the OP and then saved and then zipped along with the others. In fact, saving the files after opening them in Excel is not really necessary as Excel does a silent save for you even if the file is closed without saving. In any case, opening the file and then closing it (with or without saving) causes the file to be magically "importable" into R using `readxl`. I don't know why, but can only assume that allowing software (presumably not Excel) to create an Excel file is the cause of the problem. Note, there is no error nor is there any warning. The data is just empty (no rows, see below for an attempt to import "Book11.xls"). I don't have any answer except to open each file one by one and then close them (with or without saving).

```
> Book11 <- read_excel("E:/SO/Book11.xls", skip=7)
> Book11
# A tibble: 0 x 0
```

---

**Edit**: Note that "Book11.xls" does actually contain data. The `read_excel` function successfully reads the file (no error), but unsuccessfully imports the data (again, no error). That is strange to me. All other files, except Book1.xls and Book9.xls give the same results. That is, an empty tibble. All files are not empty. They contain many rows and columns. See below...

---

"Book1.xls" was *probably* opened by the OP (or someone else) and is able to be imported:

```
> Book1 <- read_excel("E:/SO/Book1.xls", skip=7)
> Book1
# A tibble: 1,524 x 35
   Position `Position [µm]` `Al-K` `Si-K` `S-KA` `K-KA` `Ca-KA` `Ti-KA`
      <dbl>           <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1        0             0     3     11.3   1179       0   3076.   3.67 
 2        1            14.5   6.33  10.3   1230.      0   3030.   2.67 
 3        2            29.0   1.33  15.3   1160.      0   3080.   3.33 
 4        3            43.4   1     11.3   1232.      0   3112.   0.667
 5        4            57.9   3.67   8.67  1227.      0   3116.   1.67 
 6        5            72.4   5.33   8.67  1313       0   3153    6    
 7        6            86.9   5.67  16     1181.      0   3100.   0.333
 8        7           101.    2     15     1218       0   3130.   1.33 
 9        8           116.    2.33  11.3   1207.      0   3078.   1.33 
10        9           130.    3     15.3   1249       0   3089.   7    
# ... with 1,514 more rows, and 27 more variables: `Mn-KA` <dbl>,
#   `Fe-KA` <dbl>, `Mg-K` <dbl>, `Na-KA` <dbl>, `Cr-KA` <dbl>,
#   `Co-KA` <dbl>, `Ni-KA` <dbl>, `Cu-KA` <dbl>, `Zn-KA` <dbl>,
#   `As-KA` <dbl>, `P-KA` <dbl>, `Sr-KA` <dbl>, `Zr-KA` <dbl>,
#   `Mo-KA` <dbl>, `Rb-KA` <dbl>, `Br-KA` <dbl>, `Y-KA` <dbl>,
#   `Cl-KA` <dbl>, `Ga-KA` <dbl>, `Cd-KA` <dbl>, `V-KA` <dbl>,
#   `Cs-KA` <dbl>, `Ba-KA` <dbl>, `Hf-LA` <dbl>, `Pb-LA` <dbl>,
#   `U-LA` <dbl>, `Th-LA` <dbl>
```

I also tried using the XLConnect package and the results were the same. (*Edit*: I tell a lie. The results are not the same. This package gives an error while trying to import the file. Unlike the readxl package, which gives NO ERROR but fails to import the data.)

```
library(XLConnect)
> wb <- loadWorkbook("E:/SO/Book11.xls")
Error: LeftoverDataException (Java): Initialisation of record 0x92(PaletteRecord) left 2 bytes remaining still to be read.

> wb <- loadWorkbook("E:/SO/Book1.xls") # No error
```

So, whether this is a bug in those two packages is debatable. I'd say not. The fact that a warning message appears when you try to open the files in Excel suggests that it's more likely a problem with the software that generated the files.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to look at the data... your general assessment/presumption is WRONG !. I provided reproducible code and data. And in the comment i had also explained that the data were generated same way. Non of the worksheets were previously opened and saved as you presumed...   Book11, is also not empty as claimed, if you try to open it in excel you'll see. I don't really know the source of the behavior and the question i'm asking simply is " why is it that the code doesn't read beyond Book9 given that the data were generated same way with no prior treatment.

Comment: But R can only import Book1 and Book9. Two independent people verified this. Did you happen to open these two files before zipping them? The other files can be imported but R cannot seem to be able to get the data inside, and there is no error given, which is a bit strange. I think there should be an error. I didn't say Book11 was empty. I said it was empty after reading into R. If you could answer whether you opened those two files, that would help shed some light on this issue. :)

Comment: i attempted the suggestion of r2evans... open and closing each file (entire dataset) resolved the issue... I will like to thank everyone that helped in resolving the issue. especially Edward and r2evans